# What are the advantages of using Tomcat Client Deployer?

Tags: tomcat, deployment

I wonder what are the advantages of using Tomcat Client Deployer? How different it is from deploying an application without using this?

Comment: This question is fairly open-ended. The TCD includes a number of Ant tasks that can help you accomplish various steps in your build-and-deploy cycle. If you already have a great deal of your own build process done, then there is no reason to use TCD. The actual deployment is done using Tomcat's "manager" webapp and a short list of Ant scripts to communicate with it.

Comment: What i meant was that we have to restart the tomcat for a deployment of a .war file. While using TCD is it possible to avoid the restart ?

Comment: TCD does a lot more than jsut reload webapps. Read the documentation for the Tomcat Manager (it's a webapp that you have to deploy, but it comes with Tomcat): with it, you can reload webapps without having to restart Tomcat, even if auto-deployment has been disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you just want to reload your webapp without bouncing Tomcat (see comments above), then you should look into the Tomcat manager: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html

That should be able to do exactly what you want.

Comment: I could reload using Tomcat manager. I wanted to know the advantages of using TCD for deployment

Comment: TCD adds nothing to deployment if you are already using the Tomcat Manager, because TCD uses Tomcat Manager for all deployment operations.

Comment: so how different is it if using the manager and by restarting the tomcat from backend

Comment: If by "restarting Tomcat from the backend" you mean actually shutting-down Tomcat and then restarting, then the difference is obvious: using the Tomcat Manager, only the webapp restarts (and requests to it should be paused during the reload), but if you restart Tomcat, you will have a hard service interruption.

Comment: thanks thats what i was looking for.. So if not restarting the tomcat the other webapps wont be affected ? ( ie while deploying via manager)

Comment: @shamis Correct: reloading one webapp will not affect the other webapps, which will continue to run during the redeployment.